# Nodejs request with waiting time

Tags: node.js, request

I'm doing Get call of 3rd party api with request module. The answer is following:
`{"status":"processing","estimated_need_time":50}`
So I have to wait till the estimated time and trigger one more request. And only that answer send as a result of my route. Not sure how to do it. Stopped here:

```
 app.get('/screenshot?:query', getByUrl, function(req, res){
    res.json(req.data);
});

function getByUrl(req, res, next){        
    var address = req.query.query;

    request.get(getPage2ImageUrl(address)).pipe(res);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to use `setTimeout()` to schedule another request in 50?  But honestly, I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: Is my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout, can help you do that:

```
app.get('/screenshot?:query', function(req, res) {
     request.get({
         url: 'first url'
     }, function(err, obj, body) {
         setTimeout(function() {
             var address = req.query.query;
             request.get(getPage2ImageUrl(address)).pipe(res);
         }, body.estimated_need_time)
     })
 });
```